# Concatenate Variable with wild cards with Filter

Tags: variables, filter, concatenation, wildcard

How could I use a `Read-Host -Prompt` input in a -Filter to find a job folder? The code that I am having trouble with is `-Filter "'*$JobNumber*'"`. PowerShell version that is being used is 5.1.

Below is the code:

```
# Root folder and destination folder
$JobNumber = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter in job number'
$srcRoot = 'C:\Box\Active Projects\'
# Find job number pdf file
$JobFolder = (Get-ChildItem -Path $srcRoot -Filter "'*$JobNumber*'" -Recurse -Directory -Depth 0).Fullname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One answer that worked was updating the lines: `$JobNumber = '*'+(Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter in job number')+'*'`

and

`$JobFolder = (Get-ChildItem -Path $srcRoot -Filter "$JobNumber" -Recurse -Directory -Depth 0).Fullname`